# How to JUnit Test with internal object creation

Tags: java, testing, junit, mocking, mockito

So I have a class structure setup like so:

```
public class foo {
    private DomainService service;

    //constructor to initialize

    public Fleet someMethod(Car car) {
        Fleet fleet = new Fleet();
        if(car!=null) {
            Plane plane = service.findObjectByID(car);
            plane.setColor(Blue);
            fleet.addPlane(plane);
        }
        return fleet;
    }
}

public class DomainService {
    List<Plane> planes;

    //constructure to initialize

    public Optional<Plane> findObjectByID(Car car) {
        for(Plane plane : planes) {
            if(plane.getID() == car.getID()) {
                return Optional.of(plane);
            }
        }
        return Optional.absent();
    }
}

public class Fleet {
    List<Plane> planes;
    int ID;
    Date serviceDate;
}
```

When the user logs into the application, there are a lot of operations and calculations that happen via spring managed beans. They pull all the information about the user from a database and store it into objects. In the above example, when the user logs the list of planes is populated from their information that is pulled from the DB.

My problem is JUnit testing this. My JUnit looks something like this:

```
public class fooTest {
    private Foo foo;
    private Car car;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        foo = new Foo();
    }

    @Test
    public void isBlue() {
        car = new Car;
        car.setID(123);
        Fleet result = foo.someMethod(car);
        assertEquals(Color.BLUE, result.getColor());
    }
}
```

The problem is the planes objects get initialized when the user first logs in, including the plane IDs. Which are real world IDs that are a string of random numbers and characters. Since this is a test the planes aren't getting populated with anything real. And even if it was populated with real world data, I would have no idea what ID to set it as because they're random.

So every time I try to execute this JUnit it fails because `findObjectByID` always returns a null.

I was looking into mocking or ArgumentCaptor but I'm new to JUnit testing and don't really know how those work or if they could help in my situation. Any ideas on how to get around this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can whether run your test with Spring context:

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:spring-context.xml" })
    public class fooTest {

        @Inject
        private DomainService service;
        [...]
```

or mock your objects, e.g. with Mockito framework:

```
    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public class fooTest {

        private Plane plane;

        @Mock
        private DomainService service;

        @Before
        public void setUp() {
            plane = new Plane();
            when(service.findObjectByID(any(Car.class))).thenReturn(plane);
        }
        [...]
```

Comment: what is the any() call because I'm getting a syntax error.

Comment: any() is a static method from Mockito that says anything can get passed for that argument. You are getting a syntax error b/c it requires the class for that argument to be passed, so it should be `any(Car.class))`. Docs on Matchers: https://mockito.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/Matchers.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not neccessary to use always frameworks, e.g.:

```
public class foo 
{
    private final DomainService service;
    private final IFleetFactory fleetFactory;

    public foo(final IFleetFactory factory)
    {
        this.fleetFactory = factory;
    }

    public Fleet someMethod(final Car car) 
    {
        final Fleet fleet = fleetFactory.create();
        final Plane plane = service.findObjectByID(car);
        plane.setColor(Blue);
        fleet.addPlane(plane);
        return fleet;
    }
}
```

In your tests you can then use a simple Dummy
or a Mock instance of IFleetFactory.

But in general i think your class design is wrong,
your method someMethod use only methods from other classes.
What about to make a constructor public Fleet(Car car, IDomainService service) with the code
of someMethod , the you also have not the problem with the new ...